# Smart Modal disabling window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, modal-dialog

The contractor that did our site used a version of smart modal jQuery plugin, not the one from Ben Marshall but this one:
https://code.google.com/p/esp1179/source/browse/trunk/smart-modal/jquery.smartmodal.js?r=22, on our login dialogs.

When an invalid login happens, the form seems to be disabled and I can't figure out why as I DO NOT explicitly disable the form or any of it's controls, with the exception of hiding the login button and showing the spinner.

https://www.scic.com/schedule

Click any of the register links that have a price showing for the course and then enter jibberish in the Username and password inputs.

The file that is calling the dialog is loadpopups.js.

Can someone check it out and help me figure out why it is happening? I'm about to pull out the only hair I have remaining.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The div element containing the error message, called "error_msg" is large and z-index'd over the entire surface of the form. Here's a screenshot from firebug:

[image]

You can fix this by adding this to your .error_msg{} style declaration (around line 2484 from the way my firefox sees the output of /css/c/style/):

```
 height: 30px
```

Comment: that was my quickest fix.. I didn't try other browsers. There's probably better ways to style error_msg.. you can also try height:1px and it doesn't seem to adversely affect anything.

Comment: It is very odd that setting height to 30px puts it at the top of the dialog but the text shows at the bottom.

Comment: I also moved it inside the DIV just above it and it works perfectly now., thanks again, that was a very obscure thing that I've been trying to figure out for some time.